# issue with application content

Tags: spring, hibernate

I'm developing an application with spring and hibernate so I'm facing a problem with my application content file here my code:

```
 <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"

xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"

xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 


    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">

<!-- Database Configuration -->
<import resource="../database/dataSource.xml" />
<import resource="../database/hibernate.cfg.xml" /> 

<!-- Beans Declaration -->
 <import resource="../beans/databeans.xml" />
    </beans>
```

my problem is:

> L'élément racine de document "beans" doit correspondre à la racine DOCTYPE "null".

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at com.mass.masster.data.utils.InputData.<init>(InputData.java:40)
    at com.mass.masster.data.utils.InputData.main(InputData.java:303)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Line 4 in XML document from class path resource [spring/config/application.context.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: L'élément racine de document "beans" doit correspondre à la racine DOCTYPE "null".
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:133)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:125)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:65)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:226)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:58)
    at com.mass.masster.core.utils.BeanFactory.<clinit>(BeanFactory.java:35)
    ... 2 more
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 4; columnNumber: 132; ***L'élément racine de document "beans" doit correspondre à la racine DOCTYPE "null".***
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.error(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.rootElementSpecified(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.handleStartElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.startElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$ContentDriver.scanRootElementHook(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$PrologDriver.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(Unknown Source)
    at javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:126)
    ... 7 more
```

**hibernate.cfg.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">


    <!-- Hibernate session factory -->
    <bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean" >

        <property name="dataSource">
            <ref bean="dataSource" />
        </property>

        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
                <prop key="bonecp.idleMaxAge">240</prop>
                <prop key="bonecp.idleConnectionTestPeriod">60</prop>
                <prop key="bonecp.partitionCount">3</prop>
                <prop key="bonecp.acquireIncrement">10</prop>
                <prop key="bonecp.maxConnectionsPerPartition">60</prop>
                <prop key="bonecp.minConnectionsPerPartition">20</prop>
                <prop key="bonecp.statementsCacheSize">50</prop>
                <prop key="bonecp.releaseHelperThreads">3</prop>
            </props>
        </property>

        <property name="mappingLocations">
            <list>              
                <value>classpath:/hibernate/model/**.hbm.xml</value>
            </list>
        </property>

    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="txManager" />

    <bean id="txManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

**datasource.xml**

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd">

    <bean
        class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="location">
            <value>properties/database.properties</value>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}" />
        <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}" />
        <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}" />
        <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a problem in your configuration file. The error is obvious and it says XML parser is not able to parse the file. Open the file in eclipse , and right click and choose “validate xml“ option and fix the issue.

Hope this is helpful!

Comment: can you pls share your full configuration file ?

Comment: i added all my configuration file

Comment: why u need two separate xml files ? If you done that for modualaity purpose, then why u did not import a file ? can pls share your application context code ?

Comment: that's all my application context  file